# stationary function of an integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Find the stationary function $y=y(x)$ of the integral $\int_o^4[xy'-(y')^2]dx$ satisfying the conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(4)=3$.

I don't know what a stationary function is.

Can you anyone suggest me where i can find some theory related to this??

Comment: you heard about extremal functions? calculus of variations?

Comment: i know about lagrange euler equation

Comment: I do not know if you call it euler lagrange but do you know something like $F_y - \frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}=0$?

Comment: yes.. i know about it

Comment: yes... that this it... you have to solve that with initial conditions as given $y(0)=0$ and $y(4)=3$

Comment: y = (x^2-x)/4??

Comment: I have not solved the question so i can not assure if it is correct or not... please see Fleix's answer...

Comment: The theory behind all these is [calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). A "stationary function" is one for which the functional (in your case, the integral) has 0 variation/functional-derivative. It is the analogue of "critical points" in classical multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{L \equiv xy' - y'^{2}\,,\qquad\totald{}{x}\pars{\totald{L}{y'}} = \partiald{L}{y}}$
$$
\totald{}{x}\pars{x - 2y'} = 0\,,\quad x - 2y' = -2C\,,\quad y' = \half\,x + C\,,\quad y = {1 \over 4}\,x^{2} + Cx + D
$$
$$
{1 \over 4}\,0^{2} + C\times 0 + D = 0\,,\quad D = 0\,;\qquad\qquad {1 \over 4}\,4^{2} + C\times 4 = 3\,,\quad C = -\,{1 \over 4}
$$
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large y = {1 \over 4}\,x\pars{x - 1}}
$$